# Subprogram doesn't give correct output in the following calls after the first call, is there a way to fix this?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, determinants

This program solves equations with 3 unknown members, x y and z using determinants. 
It does this by filling and 2d array with dimensions [3,4] with elements that the user defines.
After the main matrix is filled the program fills 4 [3,3] matrices with the unknown members and after that
in 3 out of the 4 matrices replace the columns with the solutions to the main matrix. 
The subprogram determines the determinants of the smaller matrices with Rule of Sarrus. This is where the problem starts. It calculates the main matrix determinant but fails to do the same for the other matrices after that. How could I change the subprogram so it does it for the rest of matrices?

The subprogram code:

```
int d = 0;
int det(int n, int mat[3][3])
{
int c, subi, i, j, subj;
int submat[3][3];  
if(n == 2) {
            return( (mat[0][0] * mat[1][1]) - (mat[1][0] * mat[0][1]));
            }
else{  
    for(c = 0; c < n; c++){  
            subi = 0;  
            for(i = 1; i < n; i++){  
                subj = 0;
                for(j = 0; j < n; j++){    
                    if (j == c){
                        continue;
                    }
                    submat[subi][subj] = mat[i][j];
                    subj++;
                }
                subi++;
            }
        d = d + (pow(-1 ,c) * mat[0][c] * det(n - 1 ,submat));
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

The part that displays/calls the subprogram:

```
Det=det(n,mat1);
cout<<Det<<endl;
Det1=det(n,mat2);
cout<<Det1<<endl;
Det2=det(n,mat3);
cout<<Det2<<endl;
Det3=det(n,mat4);
cout<<Det3<<endl;
cout<<Det1/Det<<" ";
cout<<Det2/Det<<" ";
cout<<Det3/Det;
```

These are the equations I used as a test input:

```
3x + 4y + 1z = 7
4x + 2y + 3z =16
2x + 5y + 4z =9
```

And the supposed outputs: x=3, y=-1, z=2

My results: x=4, y=3, z=5

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Is the value of `subi` what you expect after you build your submatrix?

Comment: The global variable `d`, defined using `int d = 0;` is most likely the culprit. Move it inside the function and see what changes.

Comment: @RSahu Yes, you are right! This caused the problem. Thank you for your help!